# Shortest way to apply a specific type variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, type variable bind first to last. The simplest I know to bind another type variable is to create a `newtype` wrapper for the purpose of putting the focused type variable first.

Is there any more concise way to achieve that ?

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module SOQuestionCategoryOp0 where

import Data.Kind

newtype Leibniz a b = Leibniz {unL :: forall p. p a -> p b}

lto :: forall a b. Leibniz a b -> a -> b
lto (Leibniz to) = to @((->) a) id

type Op :: (* -> * -> Type) -> * -> * -> Type
newtype Op m a b = Op {unOp :: m b a}

lfrom :: forall a b. Leibniz a b -> b -> a
lfrom (Leibniz to) = Op id |> to @(Op (->) a) |> unOp

infixl 0 |>

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x |> f = f x
```

Comment: I can't see anything simpler. Haskell does not have type-level lambdas so we can't write `to @(\b -> (b->a))` without wrapping it under a `newtype` or `data`.

Comment: too bad, it would be nice ! (or some "positional wildcard" argument... like "_3" - but nicer-  ). maybe that can be done in template haskell  with combinators (?). I have never looked at TH..

Comment: If we allowed type-level functions, we have issues during type inference. IIRC, we would need higher-order unification which is undecidable. Haskell already allows type families, which are similar to type-level functions, but disallows instantiating `p a` as `F a` if `F` is a type family, forcing us to make wrappers, and (semi-)implicitly suggest Haskell how to infer to type.

Comment: I wonder if simply referring to type variables by their Debruijn index give the flexibility needed, without the need of type level lambda : the index itself is static. we wouldn't compute it. now it is static as well... and equal to 0 always unfortunately !

Comment: Adding ways to "reorder arguments" without adding general type-level lambdas could be feasible. Perhaps unification can be extended to such cases, so to allow to declare e.g. "`T ::*->*->*` is a functor on its first argument". Interesting.